# Open more than one instance of Windows 10 settings

Tags: windows-10, window

How can I open more than one instance of the Windows settings?

It wasn't a problem with the old style, but with the new one I can't seem to open multiple settings simultaneously and side by side.

Example of the new settings window:

[image]
[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like you can as the settings dialog doesn't seem to handle it. It you could try to open it using different accounts. For quite some options the old control panel is also available.

Comment: In what circumstance would having multiple Settings windows help?

Comment: in c++ you can do whatever you want.  try posting over there.  I used to have the source for .exe files, where it would copy the exe into memory and then run load it as many times as you wanted to.  newbies would hexedit the exe to allow it to load. but not sure how this would work on a UWA.  I would also be very careful meddling with a windows component.

Comment: here is the run from memory example (BUT THIS IS A PE EXAMPLE)
https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17110/run-pe-file-executable-from-memory

Comment: @Seth I also thought about it, but it would be pointless since I want to change my settings 

Comment: @ChristopherHostage When I'm doing multiple things or want to test some combination of settings that are in different sections.

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik Thanks for the idea, but I don't think it's a path I'm going to go for that purpose :)

Comment: @ChristopherHostage: Here is another use case: https://superuser.com/q/1406135/14517

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> How can I open more than one instance of the Windows settings?

What you want is not possible at this time. While being able to open multiple instances of a UWP application is possible, the application must be updated to support this feature, the Settings UWP application has not been updated to support this feature.

Microsoft would have to add `SupportsMultipleInstances` to the manifest of the Settings UWP application in order for multiple instances of the application to be launched.

> Both templates add SupportsMultipleInstances to the
>   package.appxmanifest file. Note the namespace prefix desktop4 and
>   iot2: Only projects that target the desktop, or Internet of Things
>   (IoT) projects support multi-instancing:

- [Create a multi-instance Universal Windows App](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/multi-instance-uwp)

Comment: It was never actuall broken. This question has nothing to do with Windows 11