# Open a second "modern" control panel window in Windows 10 or Server 2016

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, modern-ui, windows-server-2016, control-panel

Let's say I want to open those two windows in parallel on a "Modern UI" based Operating System (Windows 10 or Server 2016+):

[image: Windows Update]
[image: Power Settings]

The first one, so I can monitor the upgrade process, and the second one, so that I don't forget to reset the screen auto-turn-off when the upgrades are done.

How can I open both windows in parallel? As soon as I have one of them open and open the second one via the start menu, the first one gets replaced by the second one.

I tried to start "control.exe" manually, but that's the "old, classic" control panel and Windows Update is no longer available there.

(Fortunately, the power options *are* still available there, so I was able to work around this particular issue by opening the power options in the classic UI, but I'm still interested in a solution for the general problem.)